"Trailing closure passed to parameter of type 'FormStyleConfiguration' that does not accept a closure" error couldn’t fix it using other post
I am not sure what to do at this point
import SwiftUI

struct AddEventView: View {
    @ObservedObject var eventManager: EventManager
    @Environment(\.dismiss) var dismiss
    
    @State private var eventName = ""
    @State private var eventDate = Date()
    @State private var eventColor = Color.random
    @State private var reminderMinutes: Int? = 5

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Form {
                //Trailing closure passed to parameter of type 'FormStyleConfiguration' that does not accept a closure
                TextField("Event Name", text: $eventName)
                DatePicker("Event Date", selection: $eventDate, displayedComponents: [.date, .hourAndMinute])
                ColorPicker("Event Color", selection: $eventColor)
                Stepper("Reminder \(reminderMinutes ?? 0) minutes before", value: $reminderMinutes, in: 0...1440, step: 5)

                Button("Add Event") {
                    addEventAndDismiss()
                }
                .padding()
                .background(Color.blue)
                .foregroundColor(.white)
                .cornerRadius(10)
            }
            .navigationBarTitle("Add Event") // Title set directly
            .navigationBarItems(
                leading: Button("Cancel") {
                    dismiss()
                },
                trailing: Button("Save") {
                    addEventAndDismiss()
                }
            )
        }
    }

So thought it was likely because the ColorPicker and Stepper views expect trailing closures for their configuration parameters so I fixed this by wrapping these views inside Section but didn't work.

Comment out component after component until the error goes away. My guess is that reminderMinutes can not be optional.

Have you tried using @State private var reminderMinutes: Int = 5 with  Stepper("Reminder \(reminderMinutes) minutes before", value: $reminderMinutes, in: 0...1440, step: 5)
